# How to remove object in array who is nested object

Tags: arrays, reactjs, object

I have a table with data:

[image]
When i click on remove button I know index and userID who have this data.
I would like to remove this object from "timeRecords" array and return "employeeList" without it.

### [image]

I tried implemented this function, but without result

```js
//recordId = index and key also, userID = userId who have this records.
  deleteRecord = (recordID, userID) => {  
    console.log(`usunięto rekord: ${recordID}, na użytkowniku o ID: ${userID}`);
    let employeesList = this.state.employeesList;
    employeesList = employeesList.filter(el => {
      if (el.id === userID) {
        if (el.timeRecords !== recordID) {
          return el.timeRecords;
        }
      }
    });
  };
```

Comment: Could you please add the input array and which object is required to be removed?

Comment: I have 2 inputs: input time and number. Value from inputs are connect with state, when you click on the button "add", then you create a object {id: 0, day: '2019-01-01' hours: 8'} next is for example: {id:1, etc.}. Which object must be removed is dependent on what you clicked. Main object "employeeList" is the same but with different data

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a `.map()` and a nested `.filter()` like this to remove the identified object. The .map() is used to iterate over employee objects. Once an employee with a matching id is found, we then iterate over their timeRecords to filter out the one we want to remove:

```
deleteRecords = (recordId, userId) => {
  const { employeesList } = this.state
  const newArr = employeesList.map((item) => {
    if(item.id == userId){
        return {
            ...item,
            timeRecords: item.timeRecords.filter((record) => record.id !== recordId)
        }
    } else {
        return item
    }
  })
}
```

### Run example below:

```js
var array = [{id: 1, timeRecords: [{id: 5, hours: 2}, {id: 6, hours: 3}]}, {id: 2, timeRecords: [{id: 7, hours: 2}, {id: 8, hours: 3}]}]

const deleteRecords = (recordId, userId) => {
  const newArr = array.map((item) => {
    if(item.id == userId){
        return {
            ...item,
            timeRecords: item.timeRecords.filter((record) => record.id !== recordId)
        }
    } else {
        return item
    }
  })
  
  console.log(newArr)
}

deleteRecords(5, 1)
```

Comment: @vicbyte two reasons. 1) To create a new copy of the employeeList. 2) It makes it easier to identify the employee who's timesheet we remove since we iterate over each employee. I contemplated on just using .filter() -> .filter() at first but I don't think the logic would be as clean.

Comment: @vicbyte its a very React specific issue that requires a brand new copy of an array when updating state. If we were to do any mutations on an existing state-value (ie: the employeesList) without first creating a new array, it could lead to some unintended side-effects. Although I get what you mean, why use the extra space and memory xD

Comment: Actually, we don't need a new array variable here. It is the same thing returning mapped employees or creating a new one. Since, we do no mutate state directly in map callback. We are filtering the timerecords and returning a new employee with new time record using spread syntax. Also, `map` just creates shallow copies :)

Comment: Guys thanks for the help, but now is another problem, I see the result on console.log but no on the website, If I want to see the result I must move to other URL and back.

Comment: Did you ever update the state with the newArr? @Vuzii

Comment: @ChristopherNgo Yes, when i see the result on react console in browser, state after click is updated. But i use a render={props => <EmployeePanel {...props}/> in Route and maybe this is a problem.

Comment: No I dont think that is the issue, can you show us your full-component code with the new function?

Comment: deleteRecord = (recordID, userID) => {
    let employeesList = this.state.employeesList;
    employeesList = employeesList.map(person => {
      if (person.id == userID) {
        return {
          ...person,
          timeRecords: person.timeRecords.filter(record => record.id !== recordID),
        };
      } else {
        return person;
      }
    });
    this.setState({ employeesList });
  };

Comment: @Vuzii take a look at this sandbox. :).  it might give you some insight on how to acheive this: https://codesandbox.io/s/vigilant-aryabhata-yq2w4

Comment: Will try to solve this issue. Thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 0):

```js
[{
  accountNumber: "1111111",
  id: 1,
  timeRecords: [{
    id: 0,
    hours: '1'
  }, {
    id: 1,
    hours: '2'
  }, {
    id: 2,
    hours: '3'
  }]
}]
```

solution, might look over-engineered, but this is the correct way to mutate

```js
deleteRecord = (recordID, userID) => {  
    const list = this.state.employeesList;
    const index = list(v => v.id === userID)
    const nestedList = list[index].timeRecords
    const nestedIndex = nestedList.findIndex(v => v.id === recordID)
    return [
      ...list.slice(0, index), // get items before the userID
      {
        ...list[index], // fill other pros of userID
        timeRecords: [ // remove item by recordID
          ...nestedList.slice(0, nestedIndex),
          ...nestedList.slice(nestedIndex + 1)
        ]
      },
      ...list.slice(index + 1) // get items after the userID
    ]
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

So, you want to remove a specific timerecord from a specific user right? You can map users, if id is not a match you can turn this user immediately, if they match then you can filter timerecords and update the user with this.

```
deleteRecord = (recordID, userID) => {
  return employeesList.map(employee => {
    if (employee.id !== userID) return employee;

    const timeRecords = employee.timeRecords.filter(
      timeRecord => timeRecord.id !== recordID
    );

    return { ...employee, timeRecords };
  });
};
```